# Fixed table header does not match column width of the body

Tags: html, css, html-table

I just want my table to have a vertical scrollbar and I ended up containing the whole table in a div, make the table head in a fixed position and this was the result. Is there a easy way to have a simple scrollbar in a table and does not cut the width of my table while keeping the table at the middle of the page.

```css
thead, tr, th, td, tbody{
 border: 1px solid;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3px;
 
}

th{
 background-color:#99ccff;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 20px;

}

tr{
 width: 500%;
 height: 20px;
 font-size: 17px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fae8d1;
}

thead{
 position: fixed;
 width: 1200px;
}
.tbldiv{
 width: 1200px;
 height: 600px;
 border: 2px solid;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbldiv">
 <table class="scroll">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Birthday</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Gender</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Marital</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Address</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Telephone</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Email</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: when you have something that's `fixed` it's pulled out of flow with the rest of the elements. I'm guessing you want a fixed table header so you can scroll the table without losing the titles?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

use `translate` instead of `position`

```js
$(".tbldiv").scroll(function(){
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  $('thead').css('transform',translate);
});
```

```css
thead, tr, th, td, tbody{
 border: 1px solid;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3px;
 
}
table.scroll {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
th{
 background-color:#99ccff;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 20px;

}

tr{
 width: 500%;
 height: 20px;
 font-size: 17px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fae8d1;
}

.tbldiv{
 float:left;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tbldiv">
 <table class="scroll">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Birthday</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Gender</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Marital</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Address</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Telephone</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Email</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS.

```css
.table-container {
    height: 10em;
}
table {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table thead {
    /* head takes the height it requires, 
    and it's not scaled when table is resized */
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 0.9em);
}
table tbody {
    /* body takes all the remaining available space */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
table tbody tr {
    width: 100%;
}
table thead,
table tbody tr {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
/* decorations */
.table-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
table td, table th {
    padding: 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
table th {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>content1</td>
                <td>content2</td>
                <td>content3</td>
                <td>content4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content1</td>
                <td>content2</td>
                <td>content3</td>
                <td>content4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content1</td>
                <td>content2</td>
                <td>content3</td>
                <td>content4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content1</td>
                <td>content2</td>
                <td>content3</td>
                <td>content4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content1</td>
                <td>content2</td>
                <td>content3</td>
                <td>content4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content1</td>
                <td>content2</td>
                <td>content3</td>
                <td>content4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yes Sir I checked it , But can't fix it,  I'm go for another try to fix this.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Chrome. The snippet even shows the cells out of alignment.